# systemd start a script that activate virtual env not take effect

Tags: systemd, python, virtualenv

I was trying to systemd a flask app. I tried to write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/app
source venv/bin/activate
python start.py
```

and just ExecStart this script in the .service file. But this doesn't quite work as starting the service errors with

> python: command not found

I actually ran into quite a few issues, but eventually resolved with service file:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/app
ExecStart=/path/to/app/venv/bin/python start.py
```

Without `WorkingDirectory`, the file paths do not seem to work as the static file can't even be found.

So my question is actually why doesn't script above in the beginning work? The `cd` took effect, but the venv activate didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I had recently problem with this too, and for quick solve I put this code

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source venv/bin/activated
python start.py
```

to bash shell script `xyz.sh` - which I used as service in `ExecStart`. Probably this is not optimal option but ... in my case this works.

Why this not work?

Well I wonder about definition of `User` and `Group` in `[Service]`. If you don't have this you are using `root` user ... and sometimes this is essential (other environment variable).